# How to override template for a Profile2 page

Tags: 7, users

I'm working on a project which request, for a particular type of user, the need to choose a different template for the main profile page (public page).
I need to override the main profile page but I can't find the php file to edit.
Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put [user-profile.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7) in your theme  directory.

Comment: thx Felix, but this works on profile2 too?

Comment: See this page: [Theming with Profile2](https://drupal.org/node/1892772)